# Is it possible to view your network connection speed in RaspBMC?

Tags: raspbmc, wireless

I've set up RaspBMC with a D-Link DWA-125 and everything appear to be working except for playing the videos residing at the far end of the house.  I'm pretty damn sure this is due to the room the RaspBMC is in being at the limits of our router's range but would like to check to see what speed it is actually connecting to the network at, just to confirm this.

Is this possible?  I can't find it in the Network Manager addon or in the Raspbmc Settings addon either.

Comment: dlanod, then install it on the pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two best alternatives (less hassle than setting up iperf on multiple systems to test it fully) I found were to SSH in and run either:

- `cat /proc/net/wireless`.  This will give you the quality but not the connection speed.
- `apt-get install wavemon` and `wavemon`.  This will give you real time information of link quality, signal strength and bit rate, amongst other statistics.

Answer (score 5):

You can SSH into it and use iperf.

```
DESCRIPTION

   iperf  is a tool for performing network throughput measurements.  
   It can test either TCP or UDP throughput.  To perform an iperf 
   test the user must establish both a server (to discard traffic) 
   and a client (to generate traffic).
```

Comment: `iperf` gives a "command not found" error.

Comment: It's available in raspbian repository. Try install it with the command "sudo apt-get install iperf". You also need another host to do the test with. Check this link to know how it works: http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the WiFi transmit(tx) bitrate using the [iw](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw) command e.g.:

```
iw dev wlan0 link
```

Or using the older iwconfig command e.g.:

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

And also for Ethernet you can see the rate at which the interface is operating at using `ethtool` e.g.:

```
sudo ethtool eth0
```